# Search text in String field or Date field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I a new in Elasticsearch and I have a problem for research. I use Spring data elasticsearch.

I have a single input for research and I would like to search a text in a string field AND in a date field.

In my mapping I have a field "beginDate" of type "date" but when I do the search, for example, "Jon", Elastic return an error "Invalid format" because "Jon" is not a valid format for a date.

I tested with a String field for "beginDate" but the problem is the format. In DB my format is "2018-02-11" and I would like to retrieve with the strings below :

- 11.02.2018
- 02.2018
- 2018
- 11 02 2018
- 02 2018

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do string search operations on the date field as well. You can specify the that the date is a `text` field and not a `date` field and it has the standard analyzer (the default analyzer, it will tokenize the input and it will remove `-`, `.` etc). The only thing you have to do is to stringify your date before indexing that value in elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your help!But with that, it's only going to work with "11.02.2018" ? Could I find my result with "02.2018" or "11 02 2018" ?

Comment: It depends on your query, but yes you can